# Golang Json Unmarshal numeric with exponent

Tags: json, go

I have problem when Unmarshal json string into struct that is the numeric value with exponent will alway be 0.
Please check code below :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Person struct {
    Id   uint64  `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {

    //Create the Json string
    var b = []byte(`{"id": 1.2E+8, "Name": "Fernando"}`)

    //Marshal the json to a proper struct
    var f Person
    json.Unmarshal(b, &f)

    //print the person
    fmt.Println(f)

    //unmarshal the struct to json
    result, _ := json.Marshal(f)

    //print the json
    os.Stdout.Write(result)
}
```

And the run is :

```
{0 Fernando}
```

Is there any way to make it work? Since the exponent thing is standart JSON. It seems the golang wrong interpret it.

Here the playground : http://play.golang.org/p/8owgjX9y0m

Comment: I'm guessing the issue here is that the Go unmarshaller doesn't accept integers specified with exponential notation -- is it feasible to unmarshal as `float64` and then translate to `uint64` after?

Comment: i believe this is problem is caused by type, and i sense OP wants the field to be uint64. So a proper way is to change the JSON field type to `float64`, then do a type cast to uint64 when you want to use it.

Comment: Yes, it seems we need  a float. But is it possible to make it int64? Or i need to convert it manual?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Id` type from `int64` to `float32` or `float64`.

http://play.golang.org/p/-zidTD_q8y

**EDIT**: This may be a bit of a hack, but you can add a "dummy" `Id` field of type `float64` and write a hook to cast the value to the actual `Id` type `int64`.

```
type Person struct {
    Id    float64          `json:"id"`
    _Id   int64             
    Name  string           `json:"name"`
}

var f Person
var b = []byte(`{"id": 1.2e+8, "Name": "Fernando"}`)
_ = json.Unmarshal(b, &f)

if reflect.TypeOf(f._Id) == reflect.TypeOf((int64)(0)) {
    fmt.Println(f.Id)
    f._Id = int64(f.Id)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/32HHLxnFlX

Comment: But I need int not a float.

Comment: Why are you using reflect to check known types? `f._Id` can't possibly be anything other than `int64`.

Answer (score 1):

just change the type of id field into float64.

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Person struct {
    Id   float64  `json:"id"`
    Name string   `json:"name"`
}

func main() {

    //Create the Json string
    var b = []byte(`{"id": 1.2E+8, "Name": "Fernando"}`)

    //Marshal the json to a proper struct
    var f Person
    json.Unmarshal(b, &f)

    //print the person
    fmt.Println(f)

    //unmarshal the struct to json
    result, _ := json.Marshal(f)

    //print the json
    os.Stdout.Write(result)
}
```