# How to convert JSON to a struct

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I call a third-party API and I get the following JSON:

```json
{"amount":1.0282E+7}
```

When I want to convert it I got an error:

> Blocjson: cannot unmarshal number 1.0282E+7 into Go struct field MiddleEastAccountToCardResponse.amount of type int64

I want to convert this JSON to following struct in Go:

```golang
type Response struct {
    Amount int64 `json:"amount"`
}
```

Comment: related: [Golang Json Unmarshal numeric with exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36381997/10197418)

Comment: `1.0282E+7` thats float64

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang Json Unmarshal numeric with exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381997/golang-json-unmarshal-numeric-with-exponent)

Comment: @nipuna : If the OP needs the struct field to be of type int64 (I mean if re-definition to float64 is not an option), I don't really see this addressed in the question I linked. Could be solved by writing a custom [Unmarshaller](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) or an alias type I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't explained your exact desired outcome, we can only guess. But you have three general approaches to this:

1. Unmarshal to a float type instead of an integer type. You can perhaps convert to an int later, if you need an int.
2. Unmarshal to a `json.Number` type, which preserves the complete JSON representation and its precision, and can be converted to an int or float as needed.
3. Use a custom unmarshaler, which converts from a float to an int type for you.

All three are demonstrated here:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

const input = `{"amount":1.0282E+7}`

type ResponseFloat struct {
    Amount float64 `json:"amount"`
}

type ResponseNumber struct {
    Amount json.Number `json:"amount"`
}

type ResponseCustom struct {
    Amount myCustomType `json:"amount"`
}

type myCustomType int64

func (c *myCustomType) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
    var f float64
    if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &f); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *c = myCustomType(f)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var x ResponseFloat
    var y ResponseNumber
    var z ResponseCustom
    
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &x); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &y); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &z); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(x.Amount)
    fmt.Println(y.Amount)
    fmt.Println(z.Amount)
}
```

[See it in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i_6ZMFvMR0K).

Answer (score 0):

**Amount** field in your struct is a *int64*, but number you're trying to parse from string is *float* (in scientific notation).

Try this:

```
type Response struct {
    Amount float64 `json:"amount"`
}
```

Comment: it should be either float32 or float64 if you declare just as float it will throw an error as undefined

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var data = []byte(`{"amount":1.0282E+7}`)
    var res Response
    json.Unmarshal(data, &res)
    fmt.Println(res)

}

type Response struct {
    Amount float64 `json:"amount"`
}
```

Output:

```
{1.0282e+07}
```